# jquery prompt freezing

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm using jquery inpromptu version 4.0 but i 'm confronting some problems i didn't use to have with the older version of the jquery ,that when in certain cases i have to prompt two messages the second prompt alert freeze ,i can't press ok neither close.

this an example that you can understand what i'm talking about if you try it:

```
       <html>
           <head>      
           <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-inpromptu.4.0.min.js"language="javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js" language="javascript"></script>
    <link href="example.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script>
  function test() {
      $.prompt("test1");
      $.prompt("test2");
  }
 </script>
 </head>
 <body>
<a href="##" onclick="test()">TEST</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Noting that if you use the older version you'll be able to alertas much as you want prompts
Please i need to use this jquery but to be able to open many prompts not only anyone would know what would it be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think `jquery-impromptu.4.0.min.js` is a little buggy.

Try using **jquery-impromptu.3.1.js**, you can get it here:

http://trentrichardson.com/Impromptu/scripts/jquery-impromptu.3.1.js

I tested your code with that version and works perfect. Also I made you 2 examples, take a look here:

**using version 3.1:**

http://jsfiddle.net/oscarj24/8GWse/1/

**using version 4.0:**

You will get the same problem but I made it just to see the difference.

http://jsfiddle.net/oscarj24/4qH4n/

Hope this helps :-)

Comment: I know that jquery-impromptu.3.1.js works but the problem that the prompts are always appearing on the top of page that's why i need jquery-impromptu.4.0

Comment: @sally the prompts appear in the top of the page using which version?

Comment: using jquery-impromptu.3.1.js  that's why i need to upgrade @